# Using useContext and useReducer in NextJS and reading null as context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Attempting to create a tic-tac-toe game in NextJS and trying to create a board context for my components to read. Once I introduced a reducer into the Wrapper for a more complex state, I am now getting a null error.
Errors:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

Error in then the terminal:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I believe I only have the react version installed in this project that next installs when using create-next-app. I'm largely stuck on where to look for what's going wrong. Can I not use the useReducer hook instead of the useState hook when providing context in NextJS?

Context Declaration:

```
const TTTContext = createContext();
const TTTBoard = new Board(3);

const gameStateReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        //...reducer logic
    }
}

const TTTWrapper = ({ children }) => {    
    const [gameState, dispatch] = useReducer(gameStateReducer, {board: TTTBoard, playerPiece:"DEFAULT"});
    const gameContextValue = () => {gameState, dispatch};
    return (
        <TTTContext.Provider value={gameContextValue}>
            {children}
        </TTTContext.Provider>
    );
}

const useTTTContext = () => {
    return useContext(TTTContext)
};

module.exports = { TTTWrapper, useTTTContext }
```

The context is applied in _app.js here:

```
    <TTTWrapper>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </TTTWrapper>
```

And the game state is retrieved in the actual Grid component here:

```
import { useTTTContext } from "../contexts/TTTContext";
const {gameState, dispatch} = useTTTContext();
```

---

Solved: `const {gameState, dispatch} = useTTTContext();` was outside of its component body.

Comment: Shouldn't you also simply be passing `{gameState, dispatch}` to the context, i.e. `<TTTContext.Provider value={{gameState, dispatch}}>`?

Comment: What is the `const {gameState, dispatch} = useTTTContext();` of the last snippet? Where *exactly* is that code located/called? If it's not inside a React component body or another custom React hook that this seems to be the culprit.

Comment: @DrewReese Yep, that was the culprit. Thanks for the help. It was outside of the Grid component body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see of the code you've provided, the issue seems to be in the last snippet:

```
import { useTTTContext } from "../contexts/TTTContext";
const {gameState, dispatch} = useTTTContext();
```

The `useTTTContext` doesn't appear to be used/called inside any React function component body nor any custom React hook. It should be moved into either a React function or custom hook body.